# SonarLint for Eclipse cannot find my sourcefiles, can i set a path somehow?

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I have an eclipse php project located at: C:\Users\Me\workspace\MyProject (I run windows 7) but since the source is not local, I have mounted that network folder to X:

Then in project properties -> Resources -> Linked Resources I have added a Linked Resource with Resource Name: www and Location: X:\

In the file navigator I see: MyProject/www/< all the sourcefiles here > so that is working.

Now, when i enable SonarLint and try to validate the file test.php that is located in the root of X: (or in MyProject/www/test.php in the Eclipse file navigator) I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock: 
Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor: 
The folder 'www/test.php' does not exist for 'project' (base directory = C:\Users\Me\workspace\MyProject)
```

I guess I have to add some kind of directory setting to SonarLint but how do I do that? I've searched everywhere without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seem to be solved in the latest version.